# Added dependencies to sbt sub-project tasks (e.g. compile, test) not executed

Tags: sbt

With the following build.sbt, containing a root project and a sub-project, I am adding simple tasks that print some text as dependencies to the compile tasks of the root and sub-project:

```
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
        .settings(name := "sbt-task-test")

lazy val rootPrintTask = taskKey[Unit]("root print task")
rootPrintTask := {println("root")}
(root / Compile / compile) := (root / Compile / compile).dependsOn(rootPrintTask).value


lazy val sub = (project in file("sub"))
        .settings(name := "sub")

lazy val subPrintTask = taskKey[Unit]("sub print task")
subPrintTask := {println("sub")}
(sub / Compile / compile) := (sub / Compile / compile).dependsOn(subPrintTask).value
```

and project/build.properties:

```
sbt.version = 1.2.1
```

When compiling the root project, my output is as follows:

```
[IJ]sbt:sbt-task-test> root/Compile/compile
root
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 21-Aug-2018 11:04:49
```

As you can see the rootPrintTask was executed and printed 'root'

However, when compiling the sub-project, the subPrintTask is not executed and therefore 'sub' is not printed:

```
[IJ]sbt:sbt-task-test> sub/Compile/compile
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 21-Aug-2018 11:04:51
```

This is also verified when inspecting the two compile tasks:

```
[IJ]sbt:sbt-task-test> inspect root/Compile/compile
[info] ...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  Compile / manipulateBytecode
[info]  Compile / enableBinaryCompileAnalysis
[info]  Compile / compileIncSetup
[info]  rootPrintTask
[info] ...

[IJ]sbt:sbt-task-test> inspect sub/Compile/compile
[info] ...
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  sub / Compile / manipulateBytecode
[info]  sub / Compile / enableBinaryCompileAnalysis
[info]  sub / Compile / compileIncSetup
[info] ...
```

Is this expected behaviour, or a bug in the sbt tool?

Comment: Try moving the `sub / Compile / compile` setting to the `sub` project's `.settings(...)`. In general if you define subprojects explicitly, you shouldn't have settings in the "unscoped" space of the `build.sbt`.

Comment: Changed the code to

`lazy val subPrintTask = taskKey[Unit]("sub print task")

lazy val sub = (project in file("sub"))
        .settings(
            name := "sub",
            subPrintTask := {println("sub")},
            (Compile / compile) := (Compile / compile).dependsOn(subPrintTask).value
        )`

and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Great! I'm glad that the problem is solved. I'm going to post my comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the `sub / Compile / compile` setting to the `sub` project's `.settings(...)`:

```
val sub = project
  .settings( 
    subPrintTask := { println("sub") },
    Compile / compile := (Compile / compile).dependsOn(subPrintTask).value,
  )
```

In general if you define subprojects explicitly, you shouldn't have settings in the "unscoped" space of the `build.sbt`.